# code has to be a float so how can i convert it to a integer

Tags: python, type-conversion

```
import sys

def setup(core, actor, buff):
    core.skillModService.addSkillMod(actor, 'expertise_damage_all', 10)
    core.skillModService.addSkillMod(actor, 'expertise_action_all', 10)
    core.skillModService.addSkillMod(actor, 'movement_resist_snare', 100)
    core.skillModService.addSkillMod(actor, 'movement', 0.5)
    return

def removeBuff(core, actor, buff):
    core.skillModService.deductSkillMod(actor, 'expertise_damage_all', 10)
    core.skillModService.deductSkillMod(actor, 'expertise_action_all', 10)
    core.skillModService.deductSkillMod(actor, 'movement_resist_snare', 100)
    core.skillModService.deductSkillMod(actor, 'movement', 1)
    return
```

I'm getting a error:

```
File "scripts/buffs/of_charge_1.py", line 7, in setup
    core.skillModService.addSkillMod(actor, 'movement', 0.5)
TypeError: addSkillMod(): 3rd arg can't be coerced to int
```

In the main code Java I have it set to a float or else it would not work, so here I am trying to set it as an Integer but I'm stuck on what I should do to it to make it an int.

Comment: are you using jython? If you do, label the question 'jython'

Comment: accept an answer that is most suitable to your problem.

Comment: i have to wait 10 minutes first.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to cast it.

```
core.skillModService.addSkillMod(actor, 'movement', int(0.5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't just...

```
a = 0.5
print int(a)
>>> 0
```